# How to target the negative numbers from an array, to get the sum of all the positive numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I am trying to figure it out how to target negative numbers in an array.
I have this:

```
function SummPositive( array ) {

}
SummPositive( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 23, -1, -13, 10,-52 ] );
```

This is an array with negative and positive numbers. How do I target (ignore) all negative numbers in an array, when I don't know how many negative numbers are in the array?

For example, I am trying to loop through the entire array, find the positive numbers, store them in another array, and then get the sum: `(1+2+3+4+5+10+23)`.

If possible I want to do this only with native js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make a condition to check if it's a positive or negative number, then define an empty array `negatives` and if the number is negative push it inside negatives array if positive add it to `sum` variable, check working example below.

```js
function SummPositive( numbers ) {
  var negatives = [];
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(numbers[i] < 0) {
      negatives.push(numbers[i]);
    }else{
      sum += numbers[i];
    }
  }

  console.log(negatives);

  return sum;
}

var sum_result = SummPositive( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 23, -1, -13, 10,-52 ] );

console.log(sum_result);
```

Comment: `Don't use a word array as variable since it's a reserved word` it actually isn't. Capital **A** `Array` is reserved but it's also used for the actual arrays in JS. That's not to say that it _should_ be used - in general, it's better to not mention what your variable is holding type-wise, unless necessary. Just call it `numbers` and it doesn't matter if it's an array or not. If you want it even more descriptive `mixedNumbers` will be even more explicit why you're splitting them into negatives and others.

Answer (score 6):

You could filter the array only for positive numbers and then add all values.

```js
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 23, -1, -13, 10, -52 ],
    positive = array.filter(function (a) { return a >= 0; }),
    sum = positive.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; });

console.log(sum);
```

Or use a single loop

```js
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 23, -1, -13, 10, -52 ],
    sum = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return a > 0 ? r + a : r;
    }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Method used:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

  > The **`filter()`** method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

  > The **`reduce()`** method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you mean this:

```
function SummPositive( array ) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] > 0) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It will sum all the positive numbers in the array and return the sum.

Answer (score 2):

This will delete take out all negative numbers and sum the remaining values in the array.

```
var totalN = 0;
for(var ctr = 0; ctr < summPositive.length; ctr++){
    if(summPositive[ctr] >= 0 ){totalN += summPositive[ctr];
    }
}
```

Comment: This loop will actually just give you the last negative number as `totalN`.

Comment: The equal sign was missing the plus operator.

Answer (score 2):

As a alternative you can use lastest features of ES6:

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 1, -2];
let sum = arr.reduce(((r, x) => x > 0 ?  x + r: r), 0);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the array to find positive

```
    function sumPositive(arr){
      var positiveArray = arr.filter(function(x){return x > 0});// getting positive.
      var sum = 0;  positiveArray.forEach(function(x){ sum += x;});
     return sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SummPositive(array) {
  return array.filter(x => x>=0).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
}
```

Comment: Pleas explain how this improves existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to even bother with tracking the negatives in your function, if all you want is the sum of the positive integers in the array.

```js
function SummPositive(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > 0) {
      total += arr[i];
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```