# How to find index of negative numbers in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here, I am trying to find index of negative numbers in an array in JavaScript?
Please help?

```
 Case1: var arr=[1,-5,-6,7,8,9,10,-14,6,-7];  

/*---------logic to find index of negative numbers in an array?*/

 console.log();

 Case2: var arr=["1","-3","5","-9","-10","11"]
 /*------logic to find index of negative numbers from array of strings(arr)?*/

console.log();

 Case3: var arr=["1","-3M" ,"2P","-8Q","-10.8%","-$8.00M"]

 /*----------How to find index of "-" in an array of strings----------*/

    console.log()
```

Comment: Did you try anything ? What approach did you try that did not work ?

Comment: The indexes of all negatives, or the index of any negative?  What do you want to do with them once found?

Answer (score 6):

You could map the indices with the index only for negative numbers and then filter only the ones with valid indices.

```js
var array = [1, -5, -6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -14, 6, -7],
    indices = array
        .map((a, i) => a < 0 ? i : -1)
        .filter(a => a !== -1);

console.log(indices);
```

Nearly the same for strings and a check if the first character is `-`.

```js
var array = ["1", "-3M", "2P", "-8Q", "-10.8%", "-$8.00M"],
    indices = array
        .map((a, i) => a[0] === '-' ? i : -1)
        .filter(a => a !== -1);

console.log(indices);
```

And now a solution for numbers or strings with `toString` method.

```js
var array = ["1", -3, "2P", "-8Q", "-10.8%", "-$8.00M"],
    indices = array
        .map((a, i) => a.toString()[0] === '-' ? i : -1)
        .filter(a => a !== -1);

console.log(indices);
```

Comment: I fail to see why using `map` to return an array that then has to be filtered is somehow better than just getting only the desired values in the first place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, i read *find index of negative numbers* numbers is her plural, so not just the first ..., but if just the first, the a loop with early exit would do (or `some`).

Comment: Thanks, Please help for case2 and case3 scenario.

Comment: Understood. My point still stands. You can get all the indexes of all the negatives with just `forEach()`.

Comment: oh well, I was working on something pretty similar but whatever Nina always has the best solution out there, lol. https://jsfiddle.net/wb3htu9d/ . Very clever usage of the map key as well, it's always a pleasure to read your answers.

Comment: @briosheje How are 3 separate solutions that each require two array operations better than one solution that requires one array operation? Really, I'm serious. Can you explain why this is the "best" answer?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: I just personally find clever the usage of .map and .filter (check my fiddle as well), and the fact that she is using .toString()[0], along with using the map key. Moreover, it's a sort of inline solution, which I always prefer over a longer solution which requires (eventually) to re-declare a new array that needs to be returned. It's just matter of preferences anyway, I'm not saying that using a foreach loop is not correct, I just say that I prefer the approach that Nina used. Besides, the solution **can** be unified in a single line (my fiddle works with every case).

Comment: @briosheje To each his/her own I guess. I just don't understand how a more involved operation that is less efficient than another is seen as better. `map` requires the declaration of a new array that will contain more than the desired results, making `filter` a requirement. So, I don't see how that plays into it. Sure, it's always fun to see clever ways to solve a problem, but clever for the sake of clever is rarely the best solution.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Are you sure it is less efficient? as long as it can't be proven I wouldn't argue that it's less efficient. JSPerfs is apparently telling me that my solution (which is pretty similar to Nina's one) is 20% faster than your (https://jsperf.com/fnvsinline/1), though I don't really rely on such tests (since they are not that relevant in this case to be honest). In any case, I don't understand the hate here. It's just a set of beautiful different approaches: probably harder to maintain, but slightly different from an ordinary foreach. Once again, it's just matter of preferences here.

Comment: @briosheje There's no "hate", I'm honestly trying to understand why this answer is preferred over mine, that's why I'm asking. Ultimately, in order to work, both `map` and `filter` have to enumerate the array and each returns a new array, so that's two iterations through the array vs. one and a total of 3 arrays used (counting the original) vs. 2. Clearly, this solution is less efficient.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: to answer to your question, I prefere this answer to your (despite I still gave a +1 to your as well) because it's more concise and does a clever usage of the map and filter operator over calling a function that uses an array declaration inside it. It's just shorter, hence I prefere it (and many other does maybe). That said, it's good to have a wider variety of solutions. Your is great, like Nina's solution is great as well, hence why I did up vote both: because these both are great (but way different) solutions.

Comment: @briosheje Thanks for your feedback. By the way, I set up a JSPerf on both solutions, and mine is 15% faster (https://jsperf.com/array-map-array-filter-vs-array-foreach/1) - no small difference, especially on such small arrays. Imagine the difference on production level samples.

Comment: @briosheje FYI, I have added your code solution to the **[JS Perf](https://jsperf.com/array-map-array-filter-vs-array-foreach)** tests and, as expected, it consistently is slower than my solution as well. There's just no getting around more iterations and more arrays being needed in your and Nina's solutions.

Comment: @briosheje Also, your solution will fail if `-` appears in any other position in a string, other than the first.

Comment: @ScottMarcus : That's true indeed (didn't think about how the function declaration would have slowered that), but I still prefere my or nina's solution concerning code length and consistency. It's still good to know that using forEach is more efficient (also, thanks for pointing out the array iterations), but if I would need to write it for someone or at work, I would likely use filter and map, it's just shorter and, unless you need to elaborate a significant amount of data, I would argue that you probably won't notice the performance difference :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** looping method and regular expressions.

Here's a single function that will handle all 3 of your scenarios.

```js
var arr = [1,-5,-6,7,8,9,10,-14,6,-7];
var arr2 = ["1","-3","5","-9","-10","11"];
var arr3 = ["1","-3M" ,"2P","-8Q","-10.8%","-$8.00M"];

function getNegatives(arr){
  var results =[];
  arr.forEach(function(item, index){
    // If item is a string, remove all non-numeric characters and then convert to a number
    var newItem = (typeof item === "string") ? parseFloat(item.replace(/[^-\d\.]/g,'')) : item;
    if(newItem < 0){ results.push(index); }
  });
  console.log(results);
}

getNegatives(arr);
getNegatives(arr2);
getNegatives(arr3);
```

Comment: Thanks, Please help for case2 and case3.

Comment: @ManzerAhmad See my updated answer for a single function that handles all of your scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using  `for` loop and `if` condition.

```js
var arr = [1,-5,-6,7,8,9,10,-14,6,-7];
var negativeNumbersIndexs = [];
var i; // for the loop
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr[i] < 0){
        negativeNumbersIndexs.push(i)
    }
}

console.log(negativeNumbersIndexs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for like this.

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i] < 0) {
    console.log("Index " + i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
var arr = [1,-5,-6,7,8,9,10,-14,6,-7];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < 0) {
      console.log(arr[i] +  " is at index: " +  i);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two other just about identical answers that were posted prior to yours. What value does your answer provide?

Comment: @Scott Marcus  I help this link to answered that problem.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227381/how-to-target-e-negative-number-from-an-array-and-get-the-sum-of-all-positive-n

Comment: Your answer didn't include that link. It just recreated the same code that two other answers that were already here have.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=[1,-5,-6,7,8,9,10,-14,6,-7];
var res = arr.reduce( function(out, a, i) {
   return a<0 ? out.concat([i]) : out;
},[]);
console.log( res );
```

Comment: Yup, there was at typo

Answer (score 0):

**Case1**: finding index of negative numbers in an array of numbers:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] < 0){
       console.log(i);
    }
}
```

**Case2**: finding index of negative numbers in an array of strings:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Number(arr[i]) < 0){
       console.log(i);
    }
}
```

**Case3**: finding index of negative "-" in an array of strings:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].charAt(0) === "-"){
       console.log(i);
    }
}
```

**Note**:
you can use solution of case3 in case2 also it will work fine in both cases.